# How to get username password for GrapheneDB addon on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j, graphenedb

I want to connect to the graphenedb url from my node.js application,
it is mentioned in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/graphenedb#environment-variables) , to configure

> $ heroku config:get GRAPHENEDB_URL
>
> http://:@resourceId.station-name.stations.graphenedb.com:24789/db/data

but where can i get the username and password to include in the url ?
i have tried connecting directly using neo4j-driver with `bolt://` url, with default username: `neo4j` password: `neo4j`, it returned

> Neo4jError: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

Answer (score 0):

GrapheneDB has its own authentication system. Follow the [documentation to create a GrapheneDB username and password](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/graphenedb-database-users).

Comment: There is no 'create user' option in the 'connections' tab when opened from heroku.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd prompt type

For Url

> heroku config:get GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_URL -a appname

For username

> heroku config:get GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_USER -a appname

For password

> heroku config:get GRAPHENEDB_BOLT_PASSWORD -a appname